# Discord.js | Asking for Input through DM'S

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I make my bot do !giveaway @somebody and dms them something and then waits for Yes or No then dms them again saying Whats your username and then the bot dms it to the user who used the command.

Current code so far.

```
     if(command === "send") {
     if(message.author.id !== "593964642934718494" ) {return message.channel.send("You cannot use this command! Only MHA 5 can.")}
      let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
     member.send(`Current Group Link (hi) `)
     const embed = {
      "description": "Sent a group link to the user, successfully.",
      "color": 839999,
      "timestamp": (n)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a [`MessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector), you can follow [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors) which will help you understand how to use `MessageCollector`s

Comment: Can you give me a snippet.

Comment: @HeyImJustEpic Linked guide explains the topic